# CefSharp Wpf Missing Method

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp, rhino3d

I'm working on this plugin for Rhino (a 3D modelling software) that opens a web page, therefore I'm trying to use CefSharp in a WPF window.

As a simple proof of concept right now I'm just trying to open a browser that will show Google. Super simple, but not working as I keep getting this error:
*System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void CefSharp.IFrameHandler.OnFrameAttached(CefSharp.IWebBrowser, CefSharp.IBrowser, CefSharp.IFrame)'.'*

My window:

```
<Window x:Class="UI.PrototypeBrowser"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PrototypeBrowser" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Grid>
    <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="Browser" Address="www.google.com"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class PrototypeBrowser : Window
{
    public PrototypeBrowser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
    }
}
```

The Rhino command that calls the WPF window (not sure if it's useful):

```
    protected override Result RunCommand(RhinoDoc doc, RunMode mode)
    {
        PrototypeBrowser browser = new PrototypeBrowser();
        browser.ShowDialog();

        return Result.Success;
    }
```

And this is thelist of packages I'm using in my solution:
[image: packages]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample provides a working example. Missing method exception is usually caused by a dll version mismatch.

Comment: Yeah I was following that example, although the wpf one wasn't super clear to me.
And I'm using CefSharp.Wpf v 94.4.50

Comment: What wasn't clear exactly? Are you using the browser in your application or are you creating a plugin? Does the minimal example run as expected?

Comment: I wasn't too clear on behaviours and converters but I thought that part wasn't too important. Also the fact that it doesn't call Cef.Initialize. But yeah it was running great!  
I'm creating a plugin for Rhino that simply opens a WPF window that contains a ChromiumWebBrowser which shows www.google.com (just simple proof of concept for now)

Comment: Does Rhino or one of its other plugins already use CefSharp? If so you'd have to use the exact same version.

Comment: I just double-checked to be sure, but no Rhino or its plugins doesn't use cefsharp anywhere....

Comment: The OnFrameAttached had an additional param added in version 94, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/db877d73ec33fd3b9aac47870637f1b7f350ed03#diff-f2d9b3d6666fedc7ed566aaaa808cfca148fb50af70fa79059cd8b03b711cc88R21 is there any way your mixing versions in your solution?

Comment: I'm just referencing CefSharp v94.4.50 once so I don't think so. I updated the post adding a screenshot of the list of dependencies.

Comment: @amaitland following your comment that the additional input started in v94, I uninstalled it and installed v93 and it works. It's a workaround, but if you want to post a reply with your comment I can then accept it as a solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still puzzled as to the cause, tested with the minimum example and adding a frame handler works as expected. Interesting to know v93 works. I'll hold off on posting an answer until I know the root cause. Obviously you can self answer.